# Deleting image in folder that are NOT listed in a mysql database via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

**My Objective:**
To delete images in a folder that are not listed in a mysql database.
I want this to be able to run when I logout of my portal.
Any idea on how to do this? Thanks

**The Database**
Database Name: Imagelist

```
id, image, thumbnail  
1, image1.jpg, image1thumb.jpg  
2, image2.jpg, image2thumb.jpg  
3, image3.jpg, image3thumb.jpg
```

**The Folder**
Folder Name: images

```
image1.jpg  
image1thumb.jpg  
image2.jpg  
random1.jpg  
image2thumb.jpg  
image3.jpg  
mage3thumb.jpg  
random2.jpg      
etc...
```

Comment: Create an array *a1* of your folder images names with [scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) and another array of your mysql listed files. 

For every item in *a1* check that it is contained in *a2*, if it's not contained then delete the file represented by item with [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Comment: Just to add.. what you posted was a description of what you want to write, but you failed to ask any question or provide any code you want help with. In StackOverflow official terms, this is "not a real question". Please come with something more specific next time; this isn't a free coding service, it's a repository of answers to recurring programming questions that can't be answered with minimal research ([yours can](http://www.php.net/manual/en/funcref.php)).

Comment: @kmels I want to look, how you will handle 2 arrays with 10000000 items in each, lol.

Comment: @OZ_, scanning the folder is O(n), getting data from MySQL is O(n) and individual array lookups are O(1). So for "2 arrays with 10000000 items" it would still take a c*10000000 operations (c is small). I don't see what you are worried about.

Comment: @Sukumar, wrong calculations. Arrays comparison is O(n*m) (where n and m is count of elements in A1 and A2), scanning folders is O(n*2), where n is count of files in folder. And what is I'm worry about is memory usage and performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can get image filename in alphabetical order using

`SELECT image, thumbnail FROM imagelist ORDER BY image`

and later get list of all files using [scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function of php. this will give you all files in directory by default.

then you can fetch row one by one if this matches with array value

If yes, continue to next array value and fecth row

If no, delete file with using [unlink](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) php function,
then move to next array value till value matches with row value. If it matches continue as above step.

This way you can do this task in one mysql query and one dirscan.

Answer (score 0):

Scan the folder with [readdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) and check each path, if this path exists in your table.